# Apple Mach -O Linker Error when using Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps-sdk-ios

I installed the Google Maps SDK using CocoaPods. When compiling, I have an error :

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I installed all those framework :

```
AVFoundation.framework
CoreData.framework
CoreLocation.framework
CoreText.framework
GLKit.framework
ImageIO.framework
libc++.dylib
libicucore.dylib
libz.dylib
OpenGLES.framework
QuartzCore.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
libstdc++.dylib
CoreBlueTooth.framework
Accelerate.framework
```

I also deleted the "Armv7s" on the valid architecture in the build settings, as some people said on other threads, but I still get the linker error. Is there a way to bypass that ?

Answer (score 2):

Add following line in your Other Linker Flags.

$(inherited)

Answer (score 0):

Add Keys to Other Linker Flags in Build Setting.

```
-all_load
-lc++
-ObjC
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

I deleted all the values from **'Other Linker Flags**' and it works fine for me.
I am using Swift 3.0 and Objective-c in a project and added Manually Google Maps in project.